# Are there problems with using types to represent data that can be restricted by permissions?

Tags: typescript, types, graphql

I'm working with a TypeScript and GraphQL system where the results of some GQL requests can be modified by the level of permission the user has to the system. We'll take a simplified view of quotes and line items as an example.

A user can request to see a quote and part of a quote is a set of line items with price and quantity. Some users are able to see the price and some can't. Currently we're managing the optionality here by just allowing most fields to be nullable. But this has proved to be difficult to manage and doesn't represent the system very well. We'd like to use the TypeScript and GraphQL type systems to be more helpful to us and more representative of the system.

One thought we had was to create types to represent the data that can be returned at each permission level. For example,

```
interface LineItemWithPricing {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  cost: number;
  taxable: boolean;
  quantity: number;
}

interface LineItemWithoutPricing {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  quantity: number;
}

... (there's more to a line item than this and other combinations of fields are possible)

type LineItem = LineItemWithPricing | LineItemWithoutPricing | <other options>;
```

(There's stuff we could do with `Pick` and `Omit`, etc. to share structure, but I'm omitting that for clarity.)

My main question is for systems where data values and API return types can be modified by permission levels does it seem like a sensible option to make that part of the type system. Is there a more standard way of representing this? Are there better options out there?

We've implemented some of the type options and it's certainly possible to represent our system using sets of types like this. The big unknown is if we'll run into issues with long term maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

No - I have worked with both typed and un-typed languages - types essentially enforce business rules and clarity. Think about it like this, if your type system is faulty, your data that your app generates will be faulty. As organisations grow, the types will only gain importance as a software feature in your propriety code base. So, thank me later

There are almost always better options in software - one is to enforce business logic in the lower most layer of your data stack (usually the DB level) - combined with types will give you a powerful combination, leading to better generated data overall